# Flash - how can I make ¿ appear in flash application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

I have a dynamic textfield and I am trying to set the contents to some text that is localized for spanish. The '¿' will not appear.

I have done some googling and tried using the unicode escape '\u00BF' but it does not have any effect. The font is Bold Italic and I have chose 'Embed'.

How do you get Latin charaters to appear in flash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely the font you are using doesn't support it. Try a different font, and if it isn't one included as standard with Windows or Flash Player, be sure to embed it.